# How can i set the User Agent for child windows with QTWebEngine?

Tags: qt, c++11, qtwebengine, qt5.8

I created my own Webbrowser with QtWebEngine. Now I would like to set the User Agent with `this->page()->profile()->setHttpUserAgent(USER_AGENT);`. This works well for the main view.

If i create a new `myWebEngineView` inside the methode `createWindow` of `myWebEngineView` the User Agent will be the default User Agent of QtWebEngine.

`myWebEngineView` is a subclass of `QWebEngineView`.

How can I set the User Agent for all views?

Comment: `QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()->setHttpUserAgent(...)` ?

Comment: Thank you, but both hints don't change the user agent in a new window or popup window.

Comment: I created a subclass of QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor and changed the User Agent this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the user agent in the newly created window again:

```
QWebEngineView* WebEngineView::createWindow( QWebEnginePage::WebWindowType type ) {
    QWebEngineView* view = createView(); // your function to create a new tab or sth like this
    view->page()->profile()->setHttpUserAgent( "" );
    view->page()->profile()->setHttpUserAgent( "Mozilla/5.0( YOUR USER AGENT )" );
    return view;
}
```

The user agent needs to be set twice, else its not transferred to the pages, see also [ProfileAdapter::setHttpUserAgent(const QString &userAgent)](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/src/core/profile_adapter.cpp#n346).